# Parsing XML server logs using java and sending them to database

Tags: java, xml, oracle, parsing, dom

I have been assigned a task to parse the server logs (xml file), find for a particular string in complete XML file and then storing only particular node information to Database.

Below is the scenario :

throughout XML file java code will be looking for "Start Daemon DaemonMsg_TriggerForceDequeue" String. where ever this string will be found, whole node will be picked by java code and that complete node information will be sent to oracle database in rows/column format.

I am newbie, can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add an example of the XML.

Comment: This question is basically just a more specific XML parsing question.  There are plenty of good tutorials, and stack overflow questions covering this topic.  Here's a simple tutorial, or check the right hand margins for a related topic: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to search in an XML document is with XPath.

With out seeing the XML document it's hard to be more specific but this XPath statement will search all nodes and return those containing the given value:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Start Daemon DaemonMsg_TriggerForceDequeue')
```

Combining this with the Java XPath API you'll end up with something like this:

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath.compile("//*[contains(text(), 'Start Daemon DaemonMsg_TriggerForceDequeue')").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

You haven't given enough detail regarding the database part of the question, so I can only given very general advice.

The *standard* way to store XML in a database is to use a CLOB.  Standard JDBC supports this as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html).

As you're using Oracle, you might also conside their custom [XML Type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/t_xml.htm).  This is non-standard and is supported with extensions to JDBC described [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb11jav.htm&ei=Fy3QUs3hF4SshQeY7oDICQ&usg=AFQjCNEFAI5gS8Jw4xpUcsZ_RYGp6mvq5A&sig2=hgLNmbmdUTmR4dA_lHphSQ&bvm=bv.59026428,d.ZG4).